# Grails multiple action methods

Tags: grails

In my view I call my action method like this:

```
<form class="my_form" action="${portletResponse.createActionURL()}" method='post'>
.....
<g:actionSubmit value="Save"/>
```

This takes me to my action method:

```
def actionView = {
//.... do stuff
}
```

However, I want to add more buttons in my view that call different action methods. One action might delete a row of data in one object. Another might create a row of data in another object. So my question is why does the createActionURL() call the actionView method in the controller and how can I implement multiple action methods for different types of actions?

Thanks!

Comment: You really shouldn't do something like `action="${portletResponse.createActionURL()}"`.  You should specify the name of the `action` and `controller` as attribute values and let the reverse url mapping mechanism generate the corresponding url.

Comment: You probably want something like `<form class="my_form" action="someActionName" controller="someControllerName" method='post'>

Answer (score 1):

> ...and how can I implement multiple action
>   methods for different types of actions?

You should use the `<g:form...` and `<g:actionSubmit...` tags.  You can have as many submit buttons as you like in the form.

See http://docs.grails.org/3.2.4/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html for more info.